# Resilience4j and Spring Actuator - Open circuit killing service

Tags: spring-boot-actuator, resilience4j

I have added the following dependency to my Spring Boot project

```
implementation 'io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-spring-boot2:0.14.1'
```

When a circuit breaker opens, I get the following response on my actuator/health endpoint, with status code 503 Service Unavailable:

```
{
"status": "DOWN",
"details": {
    "diskSpace": {
        "status": "UP",
        "details": {
            "total": 499963174912,
            "free": 432263229440,
            "threshold": 10485760
        }
    },
    "refreshScope": {
        "status": "UP"
    },
    "getFlightInfoCircuitBreaker": {
        "status": "DOWN",
        "details": {
            "failureRate": "100.0%",
            "failureRateThreshold": "2.0%",
            "maxBufferedCalls": 1,
            "bufferedCalls": 1,
            "failedCalls": 1,
            "notPermittedCalls": 1,
            "state": "OPEN"
        }
    }
}
```

}

My AWS ECS container health check uses this endpoint to determine its health, and restarts the container on a non-200 response.

As I do not want my service to be restarted when a circuit breaker opens, is there a way to have a circuit breaker being open, without causing the status of the service to be down?

I am aware of the `registerHealthIndicator: false` property to get round this issue, but this removes the circuit breaker stats from actuator, which I would still like to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [1.2.0](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/releases/tag/v1.2.0) you can set the [allowHealthIndicatorToFail](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/blob/b4f5249034d5bdea7ba78980b09253a4712a4bd2/resilience4j-spring-boot2/src/test/resources/application.yaml#L48) to `false` for this.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two possibilities.

1) Create a custom `HealthIndicator` based on resilience4j's code:
https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/blob/master/resilience4j-spring-boot2/src/main/java/io/github/resilience4j/circuitbreaker/monitoring/health/CircuitBreakerHealthIndicator.java

You would need to return `Health.up()` or `Health.unknown()` to avoid the 503 from the `/health` endpoint.

2) Disable the resilience4j's health indicator and get the same information from the metrics actuator endpoint.